# make R function return a locked/immutable list

Tags: r, immutability

I have a function that returns a list.
I would like this list to be immutable, similar to the way that lockBinding prevents overwriting or editing an object.

This would look something like the following:

```
myfun <- function(x){
    out <- list(a = 1, val = x)
    make_read_only(out)
    out
}
test <- myfun(9)
test$a
[1] 1

test$val
[1] 9

test
$a
[1] 1

$val
[1] 9

test$newval <- 7
Error:
```

Where `make_read_only()` is just a standin for a function or some code that accomplishes this task.

I have tried using lockBinding which would work perfectly, however the 'lock' doesn't survive being passed upward into the parent environment after the function returns its output.
I have also looked into trying to lock symbol in the parent environment, but there doesn't seem to be a way to learn what the output will be assigned to from inside the function, which is needed as an argument of lockBinding.

It seems like there might be a way to do this via returning a refernce to an environment and locking the environment using lockEnvironment() or doing something similar, but I would like to hear what options are out there to accomplish this before beginnig.
Similary, it seems like it might be achievable using R6 but I would prefer to avoid using R6 since it is not required for any other part of this codebase and again, I would just like to hear what options are availble to acheive this behaviour.

In summary, the function will return an arbitrary list. This list will be at least a few levels deep.

```
mylist <- myfun(list(b = list(c = 3), foo = "bar"))
```

The user should be able to access the sublits/elements in a straightforward way similar to current dollar-sign access

```
mylist$a$b$c
[1] 3
```

It should *not* be possible to edit this object.

```
mylist$a <- 5
Error:
```

It should be possible to remove the object via

```
rm(mylist)
mylist
Error: object 'mylist' not found
```

So my question is, what available options are there in R to accomplish this?

Comment: It's a reasonable question in itself but for your purposes have you considered returning a function that can return elements of the list rather than the list itself?

Comment: @Hugh That is a reasonable suggestion. In this case, I want the users to be able to work with the object in a familiar way, while still being able to navigate it's structure however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of achieving this could be by creating a new class (`locked`) along with methods for `[<-`, `[[<-`, and `$<-` for this new class, which will return an error.

For example:

```
`[[<-.locked` <- function(...) {stop("Can't assign into locked object")}
a<-list(a="a",b=2)
a
  $a
  [1] "a"

  $b
  [1] 2

class(a)<-"locked"
a[[1]]<-"moose"
  Error in `[[<-.locked`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = "moose") : 
    Can't assign into locked object

a
  $a
  [1] "a"

  $b
  [1] 2

  attr(,"class")
  [1] "locked"
```

In that case, all your "make read only" function needs to do is redefine the class for the object as `locked`:

```
class(out)<-c("locked",class(out))
```